# aligning a set of equation with spacing and adding "subject to" "with"

Tags: spacing, equations, align

This is the code to the screenshot below

```
\begin{align}
J^*(U_N,x_0) &=\frac{1}{2}x^T_kQx_k + \frac{1}
{2}\sum_{0}^{N-1}(x^T_kQx_k+u^T_kRu_k)+x^T_NPx_N \\

\text{ s.t } \quad  x_0&=x(0)\\

u_{min} &\leq u_k \leq u_{max}\\

y_{min} &\leq y_k \leq y_{max} \text{ with } \quad k\leq0 \quad \text{and}\quad k=0 \ldots \,N-1 \\

u_k&=x K x_k \quad \text{ with } \quad K\leq N-1 \\

Q&=Q^T\leq0, \quad Q_N\leq 0,\quad R\leq 0 

\end{align}
```

[image: result]

I would like to add a small spacing between the lines and also align "with" with each line. I'm not sure how to write this correctly and would appreciate some help

Comment: Hello and welcome among us. Please provide a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: you can put your code block like this \`\`\`code```

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

The solution might be better, but for one occurrence of aligning `with` a manual version is used.

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newlength\aaa
\settowidth{\aaa}{$leq y_k \leq y_{\max}$}
\begin{align} 
J^*(U_N,x_0) &=\frac{1}{2}x^T_kQx_k + \frac{1} {2}\sum_{0}^{N-1}(x^T_kQx_k+u^T_kRu_k)+x^T_NPx_N \\ \text{ s.t } \quad x_0&=x(0)\\[3pt]
 u_{\min} &\leq u_k \leq u_{\max}\\[3pt]
  y_{\min} &\leq y_k \leq y_{\max} \text{ with } \quad k\leq0 \quad \text{and}\quad k=0 \ldots ,N-1 \\ 
 u_k&\makebox[\aaa][l]{${}=x K x_k \quad$} \text{ with } \quad K\leq N-1 \\ Q&=Q^T\leq0, \quad Q_N\leq 0,\quad R\leq 0 
 \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please observe also changing `min` and `max` to their upright versions.

Comment: I learned something new with your answer ! Thanks a lot :)